# GAE/Django TemplateError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I have a google app engine app that is using Django templates. I am trying to do this:

```
{% if person.age >= 4 %}
      <p style="color:White">Hello</p>
{% else %}
      <p style="color:Black">Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

This doesn't work, I get: "TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted". Meanwhile (because some values are None) this does work:

```
{% if person.age %}
      <p style="color:White">Hello</p>
{% else %}
      <p style="color:Black">Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

I dont see why the first example doesnt work, here is the link to [Django Templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs) I think I am following the operator examples close enough other than the fact that this is a property and not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Django version are you using?

The default version on App Engine is 0.96, and the `>=` operator was not supported until 1.2.

You can switch to 1.2 by adding this above any of your template-related imports:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

Comment: I guess technically I am using Google's webapp framework which, as I understand it, uses Django templates. I am using Django templates all over the place and they work fine. This is the first place I am using an operator though. Your soultion of adding the library import got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do if person.age and person.age >= 4

That way, if person.age is None, it will fail the first check and not throw the syntax error on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, as some values are none, it will throw syntax error. Better you can check for the existence of person.age and then do the check like this.

```
{% if person.age and person.age >= 4 %}
      <p style="color:White">Hello</p>
{% else %}
      <p style="color:Black">Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```